# Can't find CSS when publish application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, deployment, publish

I have a MVC application which works fine when I'm using the debugger in VS the css works fine. But when I put it on a test server the CSS won't work.

Here is how I link it:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/samples.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/62qj9/1/

Comment: define 'won't work... Are the files missing in your deployment? Do you see 404 errors? Is the 'href' empty?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimalistic JSFiddle sample which reproduces the problem?

Comment: @ReinderWit the css won't link all styles. the files exists but won't be linked

Comment: Then please provide a fiddle with the HTML output & css

Comment: @ReinderWit I really don't know what to put in the example. I have copied my HTML-code and made a div to style in the css. But I'm not sure how you want this?

Comment: I see your point, but without any samples it's just speculation... Can you just put everything within the BODY in your fiddle and the put CSS you expect to be applied in the CSS box too?

Comment: Updated again @ReinderWit. I have copied my index page and whole css

Comment: When I try to open the CSS-link i get Server Error in my web.config

Comment: And what is that server error?

Comment: I colleague solved it for me. It was some options in IIS

Comment: post it in an answer yourself, if possible. might help someone else one day...